# What is the best way to ask for a textbook recommendation?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a legitimate inquiry about appropriate textbooks for a field of chemistry, and my "standard"/"criteria" for what I deem as a good book are elucidated clearly with some examples of topics I want emphasize on, in addition to the style of textbook. Would it still be appropriate to post in Chemistry SE? I understand that technically it's opinionated which might irk some people.

I just thought I should ask here before I tick off people in the actual Chemistry SE site.

Comment: Please include the summary or the main part of your question. It'll make us more decisive, and more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

> Let me give an example of how this type of question can be a good one.

Perhaps we want to find a text for Inorganic Chemistry and we want a focus on a certain topic, there are only a limited number of possible answers. There are only a few books in this field. There could be one answer dedicated to each of the texts. The OP would select the answer that is most helpful.

If this question would be about Organic Chemistry texts...